# Javascript macOS Error: Named parameters must be passed as an object

Tags: javascript, macos, javascript-automation

I'm trying to implement automation for the task manager [Things 3](https://culturedcode.com/things/) on macOS using JXA (Javascript for macOS automation) and I'm running it to a strange error. I have spent countless hours trying to fix this myself and with the help of others. I am trying to use the following method described in the documentation:

[image: schedule_method]

As following:

```js
// Set TaskApp as the app to use
var TaskApp = Application('Things3');

// Get the ToDo from toDos
var task = TaskApp.toDos["test555342343"]

// Get today as a date
var today = new Date()

// Schedule the task for Today
task.schedule(task.id(), {for: today})
```

This returns the error:
`Error: Error: Named parameters must be passed as an object.`

When using another method (like `show`) the specefier works as expected:

[image]

Example:

```js
// Set TaskApp as the app to use
var TaskApp = Application('Things3');

// Get the ToDo from toDos
var task = TaskApp.toDos["test555342343"]

// Bring Things3 to the Forground
TaskApp.activate()

// Show the task
task.show(task.id())
```

Will show the selected todo. Creating a task with with a deadline set to the `date` object also produces the correct result (a task with the deadline of `date`).

This documentation can only be found when you have things3 installed on macOS and you reference the Script Library. I have added the documentation as PDF. The described error also apply's to the `move` method. Instead of parsing a date you parse a `List Object` to it which will resolve in the same error.

Link to documentation PDF → [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19rgsv4rzo0oi1g/Things3.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: have you tried `task.schedule(task.id(), today)` without specifying key name?

Comment: Good point! I have but forgot to mention it. Same error: `Error: Error: Named parameters must be passed as an object.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Things documentation is wrong: `schedule` is a method of `Application`, not of `ToDo`, which is why it asks for a todo specifier (it wouldn’t need that one if it was a property of a ToDo object already). The working code hence is:

```js
// Set TaskApp as the app to use
var TaskApp = Application('Things3')

// Get the ToDo from toDos
var task = TaskApp.toDos["test555342343"]

// Get today as a date
var today = new Date()

// Schedule the task for Today
TaskApp.schedule(task, {for: today})
```

Note that `task` already is a ToDo specifier; you don’t need the detour through `task.id()`, which converts the ToDo specifier into an ID String before letting the `schedule` method cast that back to a specifier.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and the clear explanation. This is indeed the working solution. If I could trouble you for one more thing. In my post I also referred to the similar `move` function which produced the same error. I have tried to apply the same solution to this function but I am ending up with a different error `Error: Error: Can't convert types.`

```javascript
// Set the todo app
var TaskApp = Application('Things3')

// Get task and target list
var task = TaskApp.toDos["test555342343"]
var list = TaskApp.lists["Today"]

TaskApp.move(task, {to: list })
```

Comment: Well, what is the `move` interface according to the Library?

Comment: I created a new question regarding this error because it occurs with a different method and it's a different error. If you have the time I would love your input on it → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153172/javascript-things3-on-macos-error-cant-convert-types

Comment: Yeah, but sorry, no, I’m out of ideas; this looks like a JXA wart, as, in my testing, the equivalent AppleScript runs just fine. I’d love to be proven wrong, but I fear all that question will achieve is attracting SO’s resident JXA gremlin. I’ve been a fan of JXA over AppleScript, but the fact is OSA scripting has been abandoned by Apple. Shortcuts for Mac is the way forward starting with macOS 15, and this kind of issue with scripting dictionaries is one reason I’m starting to think this is a good thing.

Comment: No problem! I can finally achieve the workflow with Things3 that I wanted thanks to your solution so I'm happy! I'm already mentally preparing to port over these workflows to shortcuts (I already have a lot of Things3 shortcuts on iOS). Thank you once again for solving the original problem and your time (: