# Javascript Things3 on macOS Error: Can't convert types

Tags: javascript, macos, javascript-automation

I'm trying to implement automation for the task manager Things 3 on macOS using JXA (Javascript for macOS automation) and I'm running it to another strange error similar and related to [Javascript macOS Error: Named parameters must be passed as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130591/javascript-macos-error-named-parameters-must-be-passed-as-an-object/69135168?noredirect=1#comment122220749_69135168). I am trying to use the `move` method as described in the documentation by calling it and casting a `toDo` object and a `list` object to it:

[image: move method]

I am trying to implement this using the following code:

```js
var TaskApp = Application('Things3')

var task = TaskApp.toDos["test555342343"]
var list = TaskApp.lists["Today"]

// Debug that we have found the correct ToDo and list
console.log("Task Name is: " + task.name() + " and task ID is: " + task.id())
console.log("List Name is: " + list.name() + " and list ID is: " + list.id())

TaskApp.move(task, {to: list })
```

But I'm getting the following result:

```js
app = Application("Things")
    app.toDos.byName("test555342343").name()
        --> "test555342343"
    app.toDos.byName("test555342343").id()
        --> "7Y9d97VYCysH7ujX9RS2Cb"

/* Task Name is: test555342343 and task ID is: 7Y9d97VYCysH7ujX9RS2Cb */
app = Application("Things")
    app.lists.byName("Today").name()
        --> "Today"
    app.lists.byName("Today").id()
        --> "TMTodayListSource"

/* List Name is: Today and list ID is: TMTodayListSource */
app = Application("Things")
    app.move(app.toDos.byName("test555342343"), {to:app.lists.byName("Today")})
        --> Error -1700: Can't convert types.
Result:
Error -1700: Can't convert types.
```

I have also tried this with the non reserved list (The list's: upcoming, someday, today and inbox are managed and reserved by Things3) `Archive` but I'm getting the same error:

```js
app = Application("Things")
    app.toDos.byName("test555342343").name()
        --> "test555342343"
    app.toDos.byName("test555342343").id()
        --> "7Y9d97VYCysH7ujX9RS2Cb"

/* Task Name is: test555342343 and task ID is: 7Y9d97VYCysH7ujX9RS2Cb */
app = Application("Things")
    app.lists.byName("Archive").name()
        --> "Archive"
    app.lists.byName("Archive").id()
        --> "THMAreaParentSource/5wJtGuY1hxY3gmMVKJZb76"

/* List Name is: Archive and list ID is: THMAreaParentSource/5wJtGuY1hxY3gmMVKJZb76 */
app = Application("Things")
    app.move(app.toDos.byName("test555342343"), {to:app.lists.byName("Archive")})
        --> Error -1700: Can't convert types.
Result:
Error -1700: Can't convert types.
```

Note that I am able to move a toDo by updating the `project` or `area` value of the object but I'm super confused as to why the `move` method does not work in this instance.

Link to documentation PDF → [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19rgsv4rzo0oi1g/Things3.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue with the `move` method.

Comment: Nope, I think the JXA is dead an everything is moving to shortcuts and/or custom code. Doing this with `x-call` is way easier btw